# Invoke Lambda's from a Loop and Passing Reference to Current Element

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I have a lambda which sits on the business layer (GoalFeed), it's function is to aggregate data from two other lamdbas (Goals and Users).

The GoalFeed invokes Goals (RESTful/GET) and iterates over the results, something of this nature (excuse missing code for brevity):

```
lambda.invoke( goalsParms, function( err, data ) { 
    var items = data.Payload.body.Items;
    items.forEach( function( element ) { 
        lambda.invoke( teamsParms, function( err, data ) {
             // PROBLEM: element is always the *last* element here!!
        });
    });
});
```

So the issue I'm having is that I'd like to pass (reference) each element in the nested lambda.invoke callback, but I don't see a way to make that happen.  Referencing element in the lambda.invoke (teams) call always gives me the *last* element in the list.

How do I go about passing the element/or properly referencing it inside the callback for the nested lambda.invoke (teams), so that when the nested invoke executes it will fetch data for the current element during the initial invoke?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this was something to do with how I was handling promises further up the chain, though creating a separate function and calling it with element seems to have resolved the problem.